# I don't understand why the true error of this classifier is $1/2$

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Forgive me. I am very new to machine learning.

Let $S=((x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m))$ be a finite sequence of pairs in $X \times Y$.  Assume that the probability distribution $D$ is such that instances are distributed uniformly within a square of area $2$. Centred in this square is another of area $1$. Assume that we have a correct labelling function $f$. $f$ determines the label to be $1$ if the instance is within the smaller square and $0$ otherwise.

Consider the following predictor:
$$h_S(x) = \begin{cases} 
      y_i & \text{if } \exists i \in[m] \text{ s.t } x_i = x \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}$$

Before I move on I need to define two types of loss. First the true error:
$$L_{D,f}(h)= P_{x \sim D}[h(x)\neq f(x)].$$
Then there is the training error
$$L_S(h) = \frac{|\{i \in [m] :h(x_i) \neq y_i \}|}{m}$$

Clearly $L_S(h_S) = 0$. The following statement I do not understand (Up to this point I have tried to fit all the relevant data and definitions):

> The true error of any classifier that predicts the label $1$ only on a finite number of instances is, in this case $1/2$. Thus $$L_{D,f}(h_S) = 1/2.$$

Please give me an opportunity to fix this post before down voting me please.

Comment: The true error of the classifier is 1/2 as the classifier will always make a mistake when asked to predict the label for an instance that falls outside of the smaller square.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm sorry. Could you just elaborate a bit for me. The classifier $h_S$ is equal to zero except for data points in the training sample. And this agrees with the correct labelling function outside the inner square.

Comment: Could you elaborate for me please.